# How to flatten a tuple of server ids to a string?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a file that includes the ID's of multiple server hosts that were generated with the `count` attribute:

```
resource "aws_instance" "workers" {
  count                  = "${var.worker_count}"
  ...
}
```

```
resource "local_file" "stop_instances" {
  filename = "${path.module}/generated/stop_instances.py"
  content =<<EOF
import boto3

# Boto Connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', '${var.region}')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  # Retrieve instance IDs
  instance_ids = ["${aws_instance.controller.id}", "${aws_instance.gateway.id}", "${aws_instance.workers.*.id}"]

  # stopping instances
  stopping_instances = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids).stop()
EOF
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
 447:   instance_ids = ["${aws_instance.controller.id}", 
              "${aws_instance.gateway.id}", "${aws_instance.workers.*.id}"]
 449: 
 450: 
 451: 
    |----------------
    | aws_instance.workers is tuple with 3 elements

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Is there a way that I can flatten the tuple to a string?

I've tried the [tostring()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tostring.html) method, but that only accepts primitive types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html) was the solution for me:

```
instance_ids = ["${aws_instance.controller.id}","${aws_instance.gateway.id}","${join("\",\"", aws_instance.workers.*.id)}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to produce a string from a list will depend on the specific situation, because there are lots of different ways to represent a list in a string.

For this particular situation, it seems likely that JSON array/string syntax is compatible enough with Python syntax that you could get away with using `jsonencode` to produce a Python list expression:

```py
import boto3

# Boto Connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', ${jsonencode(var.region)})

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  # Retrieve instance IDs 
  instance_ids = ${jsonencode(
    concat(
      [
        aws_instance.controller.id,
        aws_instance.gateway.id,
      ],
      aws_instance.workers.*.id
    )
  )}

  # stopping instances
  stopping_instances = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids).stop()
```

For situations where a *lot* of data needs to be passed into a program written in another language, and where the JSON syntax might not 100% align with the target language, a more general solution would be to pass the data structure in *as* JSON and then parse it using the language's own JSON parser.

If you know that all of your values are strings as in this case, you could also simplify things and join all of your string values together with some delimiter using the `join` function and then split it using Python's `split` method, at the expense of the resulting source code looking even less like a human might hand-write it.