# How to flatten a tuple of subnet ids to a string in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to flatten a tuple to a string as follows

```
network_acls {
default_action             = "Deny"
bypass                     = "AzureServices"
virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${data.azurerm_subnet.blah_snet.id}", "${join("\",\"", azurerm_subnet.subnets.*.id)}"]
```

}

This is very similar to [How to flatten a tuple of server ids to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670132/how-to-flatten-a-tuple-of-server-ids-to-a-string), however it's not working for me.

The result is: `"*subnetid1*\",\"*subnetid2*"` - where `\",\"` should be properly escaped and result as `","`

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I've tried many variations of escaping this to no benefit

Comment: To me seems that the problem is not the join function, but the content of `azurerm_subnet.subnets.*.id` . Join function expects a list of string as the second parameter. Try to pass hardcoded first, then you switch to your variable

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ThiagoCustodio.  Here's the output of the variable.  I'll work on making them hardcoded as a test:

  "subnet_id": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": [
      "tuple",
      [
        "string",
        "string"
      ]
    ],
    "value": [
      "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/snet1",
      "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/snet2"
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expression which has varying Terraform 0.11.x and Terraform 0.12.x outcomes:

```
["${data.azurerm_subnet.blah_snet.id}", "${join("\",\"", azurerm_subnet.subnets.*.id)}"]
```

In Terraform 0.11.x, it will result in a concatenation as you shown with `","` separating the subnet IDs. In Terraform 0.12.x, it will be a type-error and fail to apply. FWIW, Terraform 0.12.x is correct here.

If you are using Terraform 0.12.x, the following should work:

```
virtual_network_subnet_ids = join(",", concat(
  [data.azurerm_subnet.blah_snet.id], azurerm_subnet.subnets[*].id
)
```

If you are using Terraform 0.11.x, the following should work:

```
virtual_network_subnet_ids = "${join(",", concat(
  [data.azurerm_subnet.blah_snet.id], azurerm_subnet.subnets[*].id
)}"
```

Comment: I was ultimately able to figure this out, this gave me the desired outcome:
`concat(azurerm_subnet.subnets[*].id, [data.azurerm_subnet.blah_snet.id])`

Comment: So, you needed a list(string) instead of a single string. Man, that must have been confusing! I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential solution using Terraform 12 syntax (it looks like the [splat syntax](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18322#issuecomment-403643275) wasn't supported for non-count resources until TF12 so your mileage may vary depending on your version).

The local item approximates the attribute structure of a [data.azurerm_subnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html).

Note the use of both the `\\` to escape the single `\` literal or the simple "," since I couldn't quite tell what the desired output string was meant to be.

```
locals {
  subnets = [
  {
    id = 12345,
    name = "item1"
  },
  {
    id = 9354,
    name = "item2"
  }
  ]
}

output "comma_and_escape_char_for_literal" {
  value = "${join("\\,", local.subnets.*.id)}"
}

output "comma_only" {
  value = "${join(",", local.subnets.*.id)}"
}
```